# How to open jar file from c# without opening commad prompt

Tags: c#, java

I am trying to open jar file from C# code. Here is my code,

```
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar D:\\DATA\\PROJECT\\LicensingManagement\\Assignment\\JavaLogin.jar";
myProcess.Start();
```

it is working fine, but jar file opens with command prompt, Is there any way to open jar file without command prompt? thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Run the `jar` file?

Comment: Please don't ask the almost same question twice.

Comment: I am trying to run jar file which has simple login form through C# application. It opens the jar login form but with command prompt behind it. Is there any way to open it without command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", "-jar app.jar")
                  {
                      CreateNoWindow = true,   /*no window*/
                      UseShellExecute = false
                  };
Process proc;

if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
{
  //do someting usefull with the error
}

proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```